# Default Spring Boot Thymeleaf configuration location

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've used JSP for eons, but only now am I trying out Thymeleaf. I've found that for my application I need to add some adjustments to my `application.properties` file, and I've figured out the Spring Boot Thymeleaf settings to use.

But where can I find the authoritative, complete list of Thymeleaf settings Spring Boot uses by default? For example, I know that Spring Boot configures Thymeleaf to look in the `/templates/` directory on the classpath for templates, and I know how to change that. But where is the default `/templates/` configured? Is there a `DefaultXXX` class or a `.properties` file I can open to see how these are set and what values are used if I make no changes?

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of properties settings [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html) - you can search that page for "thymeleaf" to find the relevant section.

Example:

```
Key                      Default Value          Description
spring.thymeleaf.prefix  classpath:/templates/  Prefix that gets prepended to view names when building a URL.
```

This example shows that for the Thymeleaf [`ClassLoaderTemplateResolver`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.11.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/ClassLoaderTemplateResolver.html) a default value of `/templates/` is used (as you noted).

I don't know if it's The Authoritative, Complete List - but it looks to be reasonably comprehensive, based on the settings I would normally expect to be setting in a non-Spring Thymeleaf implementation.

---

**Update**

To add some more details, looking at two examples in the documentation:

**Example 1:** `spring.thymeleaf.cache` - defaults to `true`

For this value, the default is defined in the [AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.11.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver.html) class:

```
public static final boolean DEFAULT_CACHEABLE = true;
```

Here is a link to the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/3a8366126d51461e59bfdc5676fea334b1184a72/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver.java#L76).

**Example 2:** `spring.thymeleaf.prefix` - defaults to `classpath:/templates/`

In this case, there is a Spring class which handles this (and many other) defaults: `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafProperties`

It's probably easiest just to jump [straight to the source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafProperties.java) and look at the defaults set there.

For example the [prefix example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafProperties.java#L42):

```
public static final String DEFAULT_PREFIX = "classpath:/templates/";
```

It's also worth noting that the `cache` setting from example 1 above is also explicitly set in the Spring `ThymeleafProperties` class.

**Additional Notes**

There are also properties for reactive settings:

`spring.thymeleaf.reactive.max-chunk-size` - default is `0B`

This is set in a nested [`Reactive`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3748b234ed928c4df595ba9a50fca3f5d031bb83/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafProperties.java#L262) class:

```
private DataSize maxChunkSize = DataSize.ofBytes(0);
```

The above locations are still not 100% comprehensive. For example:

`spring.thymeleaf.enable-spring-el-compiler` is set to `false` according to the documentation. And in the source code it is implicitly false:

```
private boolean enableSpringElCompiler;
```

But that does not tell you what possible compiler settings can be, if you choose to set this property to `true` (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-spel-compilation)).

**A Note on Properties Files**

I am not aware of any default properties file or properties file template which is used as a part of this Thymeleaf configuration process. My understanding is that if you want to customize these settings, and you do not already have a Spring properties file, you have to create it yourself - but I may be mistaken.

---

**Additional Notes 2**

Taking the example of the `DEFAULT_PREFIX`: This is handled by the `ThymeleafAutoConfiguration` class ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0ddd1b6ce81a24c14518ef715527aa72b524d7eb/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java#L116)). This sets the prefix in the `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` class, which is part of Thymeleaf's Spring integration module (source [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/blob/3.0-master/thymeleaf-spring5/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/spring5/templateresolver/SpringResourceTemplateResolver.java)).

```
resolver.setPrefix(this.properties.getPrefix());
```

This resolver "resolves templates using Spring's Resource Resolution mechanism" - which is where my research stalls.

Regarding the relationship between the default prefix and the value provided by `spring.thymeleaf.prefix`, the only location where I see a direct connection is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/aef92b9295f62d008faa9ab79905a474bf3496f3/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafTemplateAvailabilityProvider.java#L38), which calls a [PropertyResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/7bc803598967ab9d5bf1eb378bd7b7c4bf212f15/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.java#L57) method to return the user-provided property value, or else the default value, otherwise.  But again, this is only for verifying that a template can be located (rather than actually being retrieved) - so that is certainly not the full picture. Again, this is where my research stalls.

Comment: But where are they defined in the source code? Surely Spring Boot and/or Thymeleaf doesn't download the HTML page you mentioned during the build process to serve as a definition file. Surely the values come from somewhere. Is there a `.properties` file I can find? A class that defines these? Where is the source?

Comment: Updated with some more notes, based on your comments.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on your answer, but that didn't clarify things very much. Let's take `DEFAULT_PREFIX` as an example. Sure, I can see that Spring has defined a constant variable named `DEFAULT_PREFIX`. But where does that default _get set_? Just because I define a variable named `DEFAULT_VELOCITY`, for example, doesn't mean that constant gets set anywhere. Where is this applied? Where does Spring actually set that value _as the default? In other words, where can I see that `DEFAULT_PREFIX` has any relationship at all with `spring.thymeleaf.prefix`?

Comment: Those are interesting questions, and my answer is: I do not know. The latest additional notes in my answer are necessary (I think) for a full answer, but obviously not sufficient. I suspect I learned more than you did - sorry about that.